# Is it possible to use file saver library with POST request in Angular?

Tags: angular, http, file-saver

Does the usage of File Saver library requires only GET requests so to be able to download a file in the user's browser or it can be implemented witht POST also? I can't find anything specific for this in the documentation and the POST I implemented returns 404

Comment: Seems like you can make the POST call... it will return a File.  Then use File Saver with that response.  Include the code you've tried.

Comment: @pcalkins thanks! Probably the reason for 404 is something else but I wanted to be sure that POST is allowed in the case.